# How to run two commands with sudo?

Tags: bash, sudo

Is there any way how I can run two [Db2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Db2) commands from a command line? They will be called from a PHP `exec` command.

1. `db2 connect to ttt` (note that we need to have the connection live for the second command
2. `db2 UPDATE CONTACT SET EMAIL_ADDRESS = 'mytestaccount@gmail.com'`

I tried this:

```
sudo -su db2inst1 db2 connect to ttt; db2 UPDATE CONTACT SET EMAIL_ADDRESS = 'mytestaccount@gmail.com'
```

The first command finishes correctly, but the second one fails with the following error message:

> `SQL1024N  A database connection does not exist.  SQLSTATE=08003`

Note that I need to run this as `php` user. The command `sudo -u db2inst1 id` as **php** user gives me correct output.

Comment: please leave a comment why you want to close this question. Thank you.

Comment: The close vote is for migration to serverfault, since this is a systems administration question, not programming.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

sudo can run multiple commands via a shell, for example:

```
$ sudo -s -- 'whoami; whoami'
root
root
```

Your command would be something like:

```
sudo -u db2inst1 -s -- "db2 connect to ttt; db2 UPDATE CONTACT SET EMAIL_ADDRESS = 'mytestaccount@gmail.com'"
```

If your sudo version doesn't work with semicolons with -s (apparently, it doesn't if compiled with certain options), you can use

```
sudo -- sh -c 'whoami; whoami'
```

instead, which basically does the same thing but makes you name the shell explicitly.

Comment: it gives me `/bin/bash: db2: command not found
/bin/bash: db2: command not found`
 if running as php user

Comment: `sudo -u db2inst1 -s -- 'whoami; whoami'` runs ok from php account

Comment: add the /full/path/to/db2 ; maybe the root shell doesn't have it in its $PATH

Comment: the reason is that there is no $PATH to db2 command. I have to the full path

Comment: Then db2 is not in the path for php user. Add a link to its binary in /usr/bin/.

Comment: this doesn't work on latest debian stable (squeeze) bash: `sudo -s -- '/usr/bin/whoami; /usr/bin/whoami'
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/whoami; /usr/bin/whoami: No such file or directory
`

Comment: @Valor you can use `sudo -- sh -c 'whoami; whoami;` as a workaround when "sudo -s" is broken. I've updated the answer as well.

Comment: In ubuntu, the result is: root ubuntu

Comment: Can you please explain why you need "--" ?

Comment: @VicSeedoubleyew The `--` indicates the end of parameters to `sudo`, so everything else is part of the command; without it, arguments like `-c` could be interpreted as an argument to `sudo`. This works for most (but not all) command-line programs. For another (non-`sudo`) example, to remove a file called `-f` you can't just run `rm -f`, right?! But you can run `rm -- -f` to delete the file called `-f`.

Comment: This answer lacks some explanations (though others are worse), in particular about `--` (the explanation is hidden in comments), and the fact that `sh` is not a `sudo` option.  This might seem obvious but comments prove it's not to everybody.  @wjl, please consider updating your answer.

Comment: I am using the similar command on Redhat 7.8 system
`ssh userA@host sudo -u userB -- sh -c 'whoami; whoami'`

The output is 
`userB
userA`
Not able to fix this. Tried sudo options like `-i, -s --`

Comment: There's another non-obvious element here, which is the difference between single quotes and double quotes when variables are involved. Compare `sudo -- sh -c 'echo $USER'` (prints `root` on most systems) to `sudo -- sh -c "echo $USER"` (prints the current username instead of `root`).

Comment: As others have noted, this too breaks for me with a `/bin/bash: line 1: whoami; whoami: command not found`. I was able to work around this with `eval`: `sudo -s -- eval 'whoami; whoami'`

Comment: What options does `sudo` need to be compiled with to take multiple commands with `-s`?

Comment: I still don't see a way to make it not escape the command with `-i` or `-s`, but [here's](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/02ff134514604eca92b8dd59eb656a59) what I've found.

Answer (score 207):

For your command you also could refer to the following example:

`sudo sh -c 'whoami; whoami'`

Comment: I have found this a more reliable alternative.

Answer (score 49):

If you would like to handle quotes:

```
sudo -s -- <<EOF
id
pwd
echo "Done."
EOF
```

Comment: This is the cleanest answer here, thanks.
Maybe add a note "You can't run multiple commands from `sudo` - you always need to trick it into executing a shell which may accept multiple commands to run as parameters"

Comment: I think it's worth noting that, as with passing the commands to run inside a double quoted string, any variable substitution will use the local shell's environment not the target user's (typically root) environment. So `$HOME` will be your home, not root's, and `$USER` will be your username not "root", etc.

Answer (score 46):

I usually do:

```
sudo bash -c 'whoami; whoami'
```

Answer (score 14):

An alternative using `eval` so avoiding use of a subshell:

```
sudo -s eval 'whoami; whoami'
```

*Note: The other answers using `sudo -s` fail because the quotes are being passed on to bash and run as a single command so need to strip quotes with eval. `eval` is better explained is this [SO answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124595/8443)*

Quoting within the commands is easier too:

```
$ sudo -s eval 'whoami; whoami; echo "end;"'
root
root
end;
```

And if the commands need to stop running if one fails use double-ampersands instead of semi-colons:

```
$ sudo -s eval 'whoami && whoamit && echo "end;"'
root
/bin/bash: whoamit: command not found
```

Comment: Thank you!  Even the subshell didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

The `-s` option didn't work for me, `-i` did.

Here is an example of how I could update the log size from my bash:

```
sudo -u [user] -i -- sh -c 'db2 connect to [database name];db2 update db cfg for [database name] using logsecond 20;db2 update db cfg for [database name] using logprimary 20;'
```

Answer (score 2):

On the terminal, type:

```
$ sudo bash
```

Then write as many commands as you want. Type `exit` when you done.

If you need to automate it, create a `script.sh` file and run it:

```
$ sudo ./script.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

On a slightly-related topic, I wanted to do the same multi-command sudo via SSH but none of the above worked.

For example on Ubuntu,

```
$ ssh host.name sudo sh -c "whoami; whoami"
[sudo] password for ubuntu:
root
ubuntu
```

The trick [discovered here](http://www.unixmantra.com/2014/03/a-simple-way-to-send-multiple-line-commands-over-ssh.html) is to double-quote the command.

```
$ ssh host.name sudo sh -c '"whoami; whoami"'
[sudo] password for ubuntu:
root
root
```

Other options that also work:

```
ssh host.name sudo sh -c "\"whoami; whoami\""
ssh host.name 'sudo sh -c "whoami; whoami"'
```

In principle, double-quotes are needed because I think the client shell where SSH is run strips the outermost set of quotes. Mix and match the quotes to your needs (eg. variables need to be passed in). However YMMV with the quotes especially if the remote commands are complex. In that case, a tool like Ansible will make a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the root password, you can try

```
su -c "<command1> ; <command2>"
```

Comment: If you don't know the root password, use `sudo su -c "<command1> ; <command2>" `.

Answer (score 1):

This is a clean solution that works well for multiple lines

```
sudo bash -c """
id
echo "testing"
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers won't let you quote inside the quotes. This solution will:

```
sudo -su nobody umask 0000 \; mkdir -p "$targetdir"
```

Both the umask command and the mkdir-command runs in with the 'nobody' user.

Comment: You can use single and double quotes and escape them.

Comment: Ok, so how come,now matter what I set the umask to in this command, it has no effect?