# Multiple commands in a single line is not working when Sudo command is used

Tags: linux

I tried to execute the multiple commands in a single line using &&, but it isn't working in the following case. It just executes the first sudo command alone.

```
sudo /usr/bin/rootsh -i -u ditest && Set_proj && 1
```

***Note: Only the first one is Sudo command and the remaining are a normal ones. I already tried using the following command. But it doesn't works***

```
sudo /usr/bin/rootsh -i -u 'ditest && Set_proj && 1'
```

Multiple command doesn't works even though if I enter "Set_Proj && 1" after executing the first command. Only the first command is executed (Set_proj).

In other cases multiline commands are working fine. Eg: cd jtest && ls

**Edited:**
Its not a duplicate of [how to run two commands in sudo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560442/how-to-run-two-commands-in-sudo). I described clearly that I haven't used multiple sudo commands. Once logged into putty, the command sequence will be

```
jacob:/home/users/jacob: sudo /usr/bin/rootsh -i -u ditest  
[ditest] ditest> Set_Proj    ***List of projectes displayed*** 
> 1     ***Select any project***
```

Comment: `sudo` is a command just like any other. You need to add `sudo` before `Set_proj`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560442/how-to-run-two-commands-in-sudo

Comment: @Colonel: Its not a sudo command. sudo Set_proj doesn't works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

simple. Put one sudo by command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

Usually, only the first sudo ask for password, andit cached for next sudos

Comment: I tried sudo /usr/bin/rootsh -i -u ditest && sudo /usr/bin/rootsh -i -u Set_proj.

Its not working

Answer (score 0):

Use `bash -c`, like this

```
sudo bash -c "ditest && Set_proj && 1"
```

If you want to run `sudo` as another user then,

```
sudo -H -u user bash -c "ditest && Set_proj && 1"
```