# How to run multiline bash commands as sudo

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to launch an application that needs many switches in order to operate so I have multi lined them using the `\` operator. Now I need to run this application as well as some exports to be ran as another user.

What I am currently attempting to do is

```
sudo -u user bash <<EOF
export AUDIO_DRV=alsa
export ...
exec application --switch1 \
    --switch2 \
    --switch3 \
    --switch4 \
    ... \
    "$@"
EOF
```

I would run `sudo myscript.sh` so that root may setup a few things before it drops privileges to run the main application. The problem is that the multi line switches are not all being passed to the application causing unexpected results.

**Is there any way to make this work as clean as this would of been or am I stuck appending all the switches to one line in order for it to work?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Self-contained examples are a great way to see what goes wrong and why.

Here's a self-contained example that demonstrates that your use of multiline arguments is fine:

```
touch myfile.txt
bash << eof
find . \
  -name '*.txt' \
  -type f
eof
```

Here's another self-contained example that demonstrates that your use of `"$@"` is wrong:

```
touch foo bar
set -- foo bar
bash << eof
  ls "$@"
eof
```

Expected result is `bar   foo` (because ls lists two files), but actual result is `ls: cannot access foo bar: No such file or directory` (because ls tries to list one).

This is because the `$@` is expanded before being passed to bash, so instead of the magic quoting behavior of `"$@"` you just get `$@` replaced by the concatenation of the variables between literal double quotes.

You should instead pass the parameters to bash and have bash expand them:

```
touch foo bar
set -- foo bar
bash -s -- "$@" << eof
  ls "\$@"
eof
```

Comment: The "$@" was exactly the problem. Thanks! The only reason I thought it was the multi line arguments was because the application was printing messages about not receiving one of the required switches to operate or so I thought. Thanks!

Comment: @randynewfield I missed the `--` that tells bash not to interpret them as its own options

Answer (score 0):

I think here is answer for that: [how to run two commands in sudo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560442/how-to-run-two-commands-in-sudo)

in general its:

sudo -s — 'whoami; whoami'

```
 sudo -u user -s -- ' \
    whoami; \
    whoami; \
    "$@"
'
```

Comment: So you are saying there is no way to cleanly present multiple switches for a single application to sudo?

Comment: You don't need the backslashes inside the quoted string.

Comment: @chepner is right do not need black slashes, need to put semicolon after each command

Answer (score 0):

You can write the command in a file and execute them as a script using sudo. The script does not need to contain the multi line escape "\" -- you can write the entire command in just one line if you want.

Also, you can build a function and execute the function using sudo.

```
MyFuncion(){
    application --switch1 --switch2 --switch3 --switch4 "$@"
    cmd 2
    # etc
}
sudo MyFunction
```