# Using sudo su command with touch command to create file with other user permission

Tags: python, shell, sudo

I want to run a command with a specific users permission in a Python script.

```
import os
os.subprocess("sudo su user; cd     <directory_path> ; touch test", shell=True)
```

The test file here is not created with the ownership of the user I use with sudo su.

I also tried the same command with sudo -u and sudo -i but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You're spawning a new shell with the way you're calling `sudo su` or `sudo -i`, and the new shell isn't passed the `cd;touch`.

You probably want something along the lines of

```
sudo -u user touch <dir>/test
```

(which behaves slightly differently from your intended code if the directory doesn't exist, though).

Comment: To add to this answer, if you need to execute more than one command with sudo (i.e. `cd <directory_path>; touch test`), refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560442/how-to-run-two-commands-in-sudo).